# Книга по JavaScript для начинающих

Tags: javascript, книги

Подскажите книгу по JavaScript для начинающих, новое издание, если можно. И как быстро и эффективно выучить? Спасибо.

Comment: Некоторые всю жизнь ищут учебник, и в один момент для себя делают открытие, что изучили и без учебника.

Comment: [Что почитать, чтобы повысить свой уровень JavaScript](http://habrahabr.ru/post/117838/)

Comment: Вам интернета мало?

Comment: просто нужно было совет того кто уже выучился и сказал бы с чего начать, а так книг много,

Comment: Многие, а может и не многие, выучились без книг. Я, например, "выучил" JS разбирая готовые решения (слайдеры, обработка форм, отправка аяксом и т.д.). Может мне было проще, потому что я знал С++ ибо синтаксис почти одинаковый.

Comment: да Ёхарный Бабай легче если знаешь другой язык прог-ия, я знаю PHP но с JavaScript думаю правильно с норм книги начать.

Comment: @koko запишитесь на курсы по javascript. 4 занятия по выходным, которые вмещают в себя 10 уроков! Не утомительно по сравнению с чтением. Хотя если любите читать и есть когда уделить время чтению, тогда читайте книги!

Comment: Не пишите бреда, никто не говорит что надо читать 100500 книг, но хотя-бы одну точно нужно. И плевать - знаете вы уже какой-то язык или нет.

@Ёхарный Бабай - что даже потом ничего не читали?..
****
Ни на какие курсы записываться ненадо, если вы уже знаете элементарные базы (hello world, for, while, etc) - открываем youtube, вбиваем в поиск 'Douglas Crockford', смотрим все, начиная с самого элементарного, заканчивая мыслями "о высоком".
****
PS: ни из одной книги я не получил столько знаний, ну и КПД изучения, естественно, просто замечательное

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Современный учебник JavaScript](http://learn.javascript.ru/).

Comment: +1. Толковая Page'a

Comment: Ага, особенно глава: ' Паттерны **раработки**' xD

Comment: OMG, вы никогда не опечатываетесь?!
*Кстати, походу админ сайта сам всю инфу переводил и оформлял статьи

Answer (score 7):

[image]

<sub>На иллюстрации слева *обычный стиральный порошок* на примере [JavaScript: The Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596805531.do), справа [JavaScript: The Good Parts](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596517748.do)</sub>

По-хорошему, надо читать The Good Part Крокфорда. Для этого потребуется прочесть какой-либо вводный текст по JS, в принципе всё равно какой, но учитывая тот факт, что говеное введение отравит весь процесс обучения, советую воздержаться от чтения текстов на быдлобыдл.ру и в прочих соц.сетях.

UPD: Посмотрел я на то, что из себя выдавили на javascript.ру - совершенно очевидно, что в ООП они плавают и готовы подбирать <strike>объедки</strike> готовые решения у кого угодно, даже Резига. Так что [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide) - наше всё.

---

Собственно проблема в том, что JS кажется простым языком и типичная книга по JS этим пользуется и после скудной главы о языке переходит к прикладному описанию DOM (о котором можно писать ОЧЕНЬ много). Но если нас интересует сам язык, в подобных книгах не остается места для описания тонкостей, которых в JS туева хуча. По этому язык и прикладнятину надо обязательно разделять.

Comment: Первая книга 900 страничек))) С моим рвением к чтению, я ее и за пять лет не прочту)

Comment: @Palmervan, ненене, вы меня не так поняли. Толстая книга - это *обычный стиральный порошок*, где вначале скудно даётся введение в язык, а вся остальная макулатура посвящена блужданию в дебрях DOM. Щас попробую отредактировать, чтобы мысль была яснее.

Comment: мне не понравился `The Definitive Guide`, изложение не очень, очень растянуто, осилил только первую часть, когда дошло до браузерной реализации языка бросил, начал читать `JavaScript Patterns`, вот это действительно годная книга!

Comment: @Palmervan, ЛОЛ, в последнем издании еще 200 стр добавили :-D

Comment: омг... а смысл? XD)