# Посоветуйте книгу/курс по программированию

Tags: javascript, php, java, c#, c++

Уровень знаний: новичок, в кармане ни одного проекта. Знаю, что такое массив, ссылка, объект(классы плохо умею использовать). Язык программирования любой(но популярный у работодателей), главное, чтобы книга/курс были доступной для понимания, были не прошлого десятилетия.

Comment: `Я хочу быть доктором, знания - знаю где у человека голова и где задница. Посоветуйте что мне людям лечить.` - вас минусят, потому что ваш вопрос выглядит как то так. Вам никто ничего дельного не посоветует, так как только вам решать, чем именно вы хотите заниматься, и уже от этого плясать.

Comment: А как стоит задавать вопрос?Я хотел обозначить, что мало чего знаю, чтобы было легче ответить на вопрос

Comment: Я бы вам посоветовал наверно исследовать вопрос самому. Например, в чем ваша цель? Начать зарабатывать? Зарабатывать где? В вашем городе? В каком то другом городе? Эмигрировать в другую страну? Везде требования будут разные, технологии будут разные. Как быстро вы хотите начать работать? Чем вы хотите заниматься? Сайтами? Мобильными приложениями? - ответом на это тоже будут разные технологии. Как много времени вы хотите уделить учебе? Если вы собираетесь час в день тратить, чтобы учиться, то это несерьезно. Если вы думаете в какой университет поступать, то это вообще другой разговор.

Comment: Про разные требования, технологии. Я не особо понимаю разницу. Вот, допустим, моя работа - делать умные пылесосы. Ябуду работать, например, с Java. Что в России, что в Америке мне надо будет писать тот же самый код. Или, например, создавать программы под ракеты, разве тут есть разница? Если я ошибаюсь, объясните, пожалуйста

Comment: Если я правильно понял, что вы имели ввиду про разные технологии. Если я хочу делать управляемые квадрокоптеры мне надо научиться работать с датчиками, передачаей данных, а если с сайтами, надо научится работать с получаемыми данными, например. Я правильно понял?

Comment: надо быть реалистами, вас никто не пустит без опыта программировать пылесосы, квадракопетры и тем более ракеты. Мало того, в одной компании это может означать программирование на Java, а в другой - на C++. Откройте любой сайт с вакансиями и поглядите, какие работники и на каких языках требоуются больше. Также регион имеет значение, например, в корпоративном секторе, в больших компаниях, в России вам скорее придется писать на C#, а в Европе и на западе - на Java

Comment: Если вам надо прямо срочно хоть что то начать, а опыта ноль, то вам придется скорее всего начать клепать вебсайты за очень мало денег. Но даже чтобы клепать вебсайты, надо это уметь делать. Это тоже может быть java/c#/pyton/ruby/php на бекенде и html+css+js/typescript на фронте, или вообще может быть готовый движок CMS, там программировать практически не надо самому.

Comment: или может вы игры делать собрались, тут вам ещё букет технологий, который вы можете использовать. Я к тому, что программирование настолько разнообразное и насколько отличается рынок в каждом городе, что что то советовать вам - это как пальцем в небо тыкать. Потому вам надо самому определиться с тем, что вам интересно и какой результат вам нужен и идти к этому результату. И вот если по дороге будут конкретные вопросы, то тогда имеет смысл спрашивать.

Comment: А сейчас у вас вопрос настолько общий, что вам уже вон и C# и C++ и Javascript посоветовали, а это как лебедь, рак и щука - каждый в свою сторону тянет, попробуете на всех троих уехать - так ничего и не добьётесь.

Comment: У меня есть ещё 3 года, и ещё университет и институт, у меня очень много времени

Comment: И я, если честно, не особо понимаю саму логику программирования, например я захотел создать сайт, вы сказали, что там надо целых 9 языков знать, а так же их как-то скрещивать

Comment: И я не могу никак понять, в программировании есть ветвление, переменная, массив, и всё, как с помощью этого создать программу, по которой будет лететь ракета?

Comment: `в программировании есть ветвление, переменная, массив, и всё` - у вас, можно сказать, нет никакого представления о программировании. Не делайте подобных выводов самостоятельно, вы просто не понимаете, о чем пишете. Раз у вас 3 года есть, то выделите месяц и пройдите пару базовых курсов, вот например [бесплатный и на руском](https://stepik.org/course/5482/promo). Когды вы учите базовые вещи, язык программирования не важен, основные принципы более-менее одинаковые, хоть в C#, хоть в Java, хоть в C++.

Comment: чтобы создать сайт, не надо знать 9 языков. Сайт сайту рознь. Вы можете просто создать HTML страничку, там вообще ничего почти знать не надо для этого. Но если вы работаете на корпорацию или на интегратор, то есть большую компанию или пишете более-менне сложный сайт, то статическим сайтом там ничего не делается.

Comment: Вот скажите, пожалуйста, какой курс по Java вы считаете авторитетным(сертификат), понятным?

Comment: Если вы живете в России, то сертификаты тут редко имеют какое то значение. Что касается курсов, то я пользовался [javarush](https://javarush.ru/), читал [книги](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416634/179763), проходил курсы на [pluralsight](https://pluralsight.com/), решал задачи на таких платформах, как https://leetcode.com/, https://www.hackerrank.com/, http://codeforces.com/, ну и, конечно, делал свой небольшой домашний проект.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!

Comment: Пожалуйста, удачи с обучением.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал C#, почему?

- Огромное сообщество.
- Программирование под: Веб, Телефоны, Компы.
- Unity 3D - вперед делать игры.
- Изучив C#, будет легче понимать С-и подобные языки
- Актуальность
- Зарплата - тоже не обидят

[XpUcT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lK7-RelET6g&list=PL05SB3rBbUsraqiEUeS70RKhVAu97nGeb) - Очень интересные и что немаловажно понятные уроки по C#, сам чел не нудный и преподносит материал интересно.

[Extreme Code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86KLS8das2k&list=PLuGqgO5WmeGPTZqDHZDIum3h7HnfBfzmZ) Забавные ребята, помимо C#, не плохо объясняют, что такое паттерны, на кой лясон они нужны. В общем канал годный, советую.

[4Game Free](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1JtLJJG5AWw&list=PLD1B2C1D095B583B7) 80 уроков, отличное начало для изучения Unity 3D, 2Д, 3Д и конечно же - программирование.

Answer (score 0):

Первый раз вижу что-бы выбирали по принципу

> Язык программирования любой(но популярный у работодателей)

между **javascript** и **c++**
Как бы вам сказать... это чуть-чуть разный уровень.

А на ваш вопрос уже есть куча ответов:

[Книга по JavaScript для начинающих](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/93666/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-javascript-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85)

[Книги по ООП PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/135291/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%9E%D0%9E%D0%9F-php)

[С чего начать изучение программирования?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/5183/%D0%A1-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

и т.д.

**P.S. Умение гуглить уже существующую инфу, является маст хев скилом для любого языка**

Comment: А как надо выбирать?

Comment: @StrongMuffin выбирать нужно по методу: Что я хочу. Если вы хотите делать игры, то какие? 3D, 2D, VR? AR? Исходя из этого уже делать выбор движка, а от движка и язык программирования(если вообще полностью 0 знания). Для игр: C++, Blue Print(не язык программирования), C#. Движка Unreal Engine 4(C++), Unity 3D(C#). Для сайтов Python, PhP, JS, C#. Программы для ПК и телефонов(C#, Delphi, Java).

Comment: Спасибо, понял!